# Creating a custom Maven repository on my web server

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

So I have tiny Linux EC2 instance up that I’d like to use as a custom Maven repository to share and host my own artifacts. I’ve attempted to follow the guide at the following URL: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073230/maven-repository-in-three-steps.html

But to no avail, on running the documented release command:  (from the folder that contains my project Pom file) ‘mvn install -DperformRelease=true -DcreateChecksum=true’

I get an error advising that no Pom file exists! Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Sounds like a simple error. If Maven is installed and you call `mvn install` in a directory with a `pom.xml`, it should work fine.

Comment: That’s the reason for the post. Maven doesn’t seem to be picking up the Pom file even though it IS in the directory. Very unusual..

Comment: Then please post the directory listing and the error message. Please _edit the question_ for that and do not put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, turned out to be a faulty Maven installation. Removed Maven and reinstalled and everything now works fine.